# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

```
var Result1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local)

var Result2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow,  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id));
```

Both this convert Utc time to local time, is there any difference between this 2 different ways in result or performance?

which is good?

why Microsoft not using  TimeZoneInfo.Local directly(as for Result1) in sample  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx)

Comment: I don't see any difference between them.

Comment: I think both are the same. the second option is used to get other time zones, not the local time zone set on your computer. if you use it like you did in your post, it will give the same result as the other option.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that the second takes a detour by getting a `TimeZoneInfo` object, getting the id for it, and looking up the same object again using the id.

The reason that the code in the example is using the `FindSystemTimeZoneById` method is that it's getting the `TimeZoneInfo` object for a known id, it's not getting that id from a `TimeZoneInfo` object that it already has.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be worth while to extend my comment into an answer.

I have an application in which the "local" time zone is configured in the DB, it has nothing to do with the local time zone of the server itself. (It is running in a cloud server).
So, using **TimeZoneInfo.Local** is not good for me.

What I would like to do is to read from the DB what time zone should be used,
and then convert the time from UTC to that time zone.
Hence I'm using:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow,  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(GetTimeZoneId()));
```

Where **GetTimeZoneId()** reads from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of how you're gonna use them. **TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()** is used when you want a different timezone other than your local. If you're always going to use your local timezone, just use **TimeZoneInfo.Local**.

In terms of performance, I don't think there is much difference. However, you can try to profile it using .NET Profiler or other profilers to see how much difference does the two have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference between those two invocations.

Windows has a feature to adjust for DST automatically, which can be seen in two places on modern Windows:

In the Date & Time settings page:
[image: screenshot]

In the Date & Time control panel under Time Zone Settings:
[image: screenshot]

This setting is recommended to remain ON in most cases.  If however you turn it *off*, `TimeZoneInfo.Local` will take that into account.

If you call `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id)`, the result will be the same as if the setting were on, *even if it is actually turned off*.  This is by design.