# .Net TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc issue for standard timezone entry

Tags: asp.net, .net, datetime, timezone

Related to .Net TimeZoneInfo I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809007/timezoneinfo-converttimefromutc-c-sharp) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545021/timezoneinfo-converttimefromutc-returns-incorrect-result) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326079/timezoneinfo-converttimefromutc-returned-wrong-datetime) and close seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352042/timezoneinfo-converttimefromutc-produce-different-output-then-timezone-baseutcof). However it still doesn't solve the confusion I have. What I am trying to do is simply convert a date & a time between two selected timezones.

I use **TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()** to get the timezone list.

I am running my code from a computer having IST timezone (UTC+05:30).

My input date/time is (stDate) : **9/Jan/2021 10:00 AM** having DateTimeKind as unspecified. So code goes like below;

```
var startUtc = stDate.ToUniversalTime();//output {1/9/2021 4:30:00 AM}

//now get the target timezone 
var eventZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");//inspector shows {(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)}

//now I want to convert above time to a time in Eastern Standard Time. 
//So it's like someone in EST selecting 9/Jan/2021 10:00 AM

var convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(startUtc, eventZone); //output {1/8/2021 11:30:00 PM}
```

So the first question- Even though my code runs in a computer with IST zone, If I use a DateTimeKind.unspecified (9/Jan/2021 10:00 AM) and convert to EST why does it show as {1/8/2021 11:30:00 PM} ? Is it correct? I am trying to simulate a case where a user in EST timezone selecting 10am on 7th Jan 2021 (shouldn't it still show me 9/Jan/2021 10:00 AM but internally mark it as relative to a person in EST?).

So that if i convert EST (9/Jan/2021 10:00) to IST (back to my computer timezone), It should simply show 1/9/2021 8:30PM.

I am simply trying to do something like in [timezoneconverter.com](https://www.thetimezoneconverter.com/) where you select a date/time of a specified timezone, select a target timezone and see the converted date/time as in;

[image]

So, in above case, i was expecting by giving 9/Jan/2021 10:00 AM, convert it to EST and then back to IST zone should give me 9/Jan/2021 8:30 PM. In my case it doesn't but [www.thetimezoneconverter.com](https://www.thetimezoneconverter.com/) does it right!

What's wrong in my code? I just need to duplicate [timezoneconverter.com](https://www.thetimezoneconverter.com/) where you convert between datetime to/from any timezone

Answer (score 0):

Your code is converting from IST to UTC then to EST.  The UTC intermediate stage isn't necessary, but nonetheless it appears you are asking how to do the opposite - converting from EST to IST.

```
// Your input value (2021-01-09 10:00:00 AM)
DateTime stDate = new DateTime(2021, 1, 9, 10, 0, 0);  // Unspecified kind is the default

// The time zone of that input value
TimeZoneInfo eventZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

// The time zone you want to convert to
TimeZoneInfo targetZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

// Do the conversion
DateTime convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(stDate, eventZone, targetZone);

// result: 2021-01-09 8:30:00 PM
```

[Working example here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SzVs40)

This code specifically converts to India Standard Time.  If instead of always IST, you meant to use whatever the user's local time zone is (and if this is being done in a desktop or mobile application, not on a web server), then you can substitute `TimeZoneInfo.Local` for the target zone.

Comment: Note, I removed my original answer because I had misunderstood your question.  I believe the current answer is what you were looking for.